# How to install sqlserver2008 failover cluster on windows2003 server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cluster, msdtc

Can any one give me the procedure to create a failover cluster on windows2003???

Any links would also be helpful.....

I got warning messages on MSDTC such that MSDTC is not running on local machine.  If it is configured on cluster please run like that msg comes.  How can i fix this???

Answer (score 1):

Try [here](http://blogs.mssqltips.com/blogs/chadboyd/archive/2008/06/29/installing-clustered-sql-servers-outline-checklists-document-sheets.aspx), post back if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The generic steps are below but you should be able to get white papers on this from Microsoft's web site.

- Present SAN/shared storage device to
  cluster
- Create partition, format drive and
  assign drive letter
- Pick an IP address and network name
  to use that is not in use
- run through SQL server setup

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179530.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to install the MSDTC service as a clustered resource.  This is described in the following article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301600

Comment: I have done those also by sseing this article only before i post the question.